# r vector of non-sums of self items

Tags: r, performance, combinatorics

I am trying to build a function that creates a vector where any item is NOT the sum of any combination of other items in the list (without duplication).

This function does the job but is quite slow... any bright thoughts on how to improve it?

```
sum_fun <- function(k)
{
  out_list <- c(2,3,4)
  new_num <- 4

  while(length(out_list) < k)
  {
    new_num <- new_num + 1
    #Check if new_num can be written as a sum of the terms in out_list
    new_valid <- T
    for (i in 2:(length(out_list) - 1)){
      if (new_num %in% (apply(combn(out_list,i), FUN = sum, MAR = 2)))
      {
        new_valid <- F
        break
      }
    }

    if (new_valid)
    {
      out_list <- c(out_list, new_num)
    }

  }
  return(out_list)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a good question. I made some changes to your original function and got mine to run a bit quicker than your function. On a side note, how many are you trying to find?

The main idea is that we shouldn't calculate more things more often than we absolutely have to. I think the `for` loop was probably slowing things down a bit, plus, how many of the column sums were repeated? If we can "de-dup" the list, maybe we can search through it more quickly [reduce, reuse, recycle :) ].

```
sum_fun2 <- function(k)
{
  out_list <- c(2,3,4) #dummy list
  new_num <- 4 #dummy number
  calc_big_sum <- T #calculate big sum on the first go
  while(length(out_list) < k)
  {
    new_num <- new_num + 1 #dummy number to add

    #calculate big sum, and then find unique values
    if(calc_big_sum){
      big_sum<- unique(unlist(lapply(lapply(2:(length(out_list) - 1), 
                                    FUN = function(x) combn(out_list, m = x)), 
                                    FUN = function(y) apply(y, 2, sum))))
    }

      if(new_num %in% big_sum){
        calc_big_sum = F #don't make it calculate the sum again
      }else{
        out_list <- c(out_list, new_num) #add number to list
        calc_big_sum = T #make it calculate a new sum
      }
  }
  return(out_list)
}

> system.time(sum_fun2(10))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.03 
> system.time(sum_fun(10))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.30    0.00    1.27 
> system.time(sum_fun2(14))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.35    0.07    3.47 
> system.time(sum_fun(14))
## I ended it
Timing stopped at: 39.86 0 40.02
```

Comment: Thank you !! Much much faster indeed. But I realize my problem becomes nearly unsolvable for large k (100 or up).